# c: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: c, csv, clion

I am making a program that can make an array from user input and save it inside a csv files. Then the user is able to perform matrix and vector operations with the stored arrays. When i started working with csv files(initially on clion) i started getting the error: "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)" After debugging i found the error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ff7b202dff8)" . However the program still worked when ran in replit. Sadly though after i wrote lines 60 -65 in order to make a different csv file every  time the function is ran i started getting the error: "signal: segmentation fault (core dumped) " on replit. What could be causing these errors? Here is my code on replit:

"https://replit.com/@iasonaszak/the-matrix#main.c"

Thank you in advance for your help!!

and here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "time.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int a;
char c[20];

int num;


bool b = true;
int main() {
  
  while (b ==true){
    void create_array();
    void delete_array();
    int user_answer;
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    printf(
            " 1.create an array\n 2.load an array\n 3.Show available arrays\n 4.Delete array\n 5.Vector operations \n 6.Matrix operations"

    ) ;
    printf("Please choose one of the following options!\n");
    scanf("%d" , &user_answer);

    if (user_answer == 1){
        create_array( );
    }
     else if (user_answer == 4){
       delete_array();
  
}
    return 0;
}

}
void create_array(){
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int i;
    int j;
    int matrix[i][j];
    printf("how many columns would you like your array to have");

    scanf("%d" ,&cols );
    printf("how many rows would you like your array to have");
    scanf("%d" ,&rows );
     

 char filename[80];
  
  FILE *fout = fopen(filename, "wt");
  FILE *last = fopen("lastnum.csv" , "w");

    fgets(c , 20 , last);
  num = atoi(c);

  snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "prefix.%d.csv", num);
  
  
    for (i = 0 ; i < rows; i ++){
      printf("\n");
      fprintf(fout , "\n");
        for (j = 0 ; j < cols; j ++){
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
            
            char str[(int)((ceil(log10(matrix[i][j]))+1)*sizeof(char))];
            sprintf(str , "%d " , matrix[i][j]);
            fprintf(fout ,"%s" , str);
        }
        
      
        
    }
printf("Your array was saved successfuly inside a csv file");
num++;
        



}
void delete_array(){
  remove("prefix.0.csv");
   remove("prefix.1.csv");
    remove("prefix.2.csv");
     remove("prefix.3.csv");
      remove("prefix.4.csv");
       remove("prefix.5.csv");
  remove("prefix.6.csv");
   remove("prefix.7.csv");
    remove("prefix.8.csv");
     remove("prefix.9.csv");
  

  printf("all arrays were deleted");
}

void preview_arrays(){
  FILE *F0 = fopen("prefix.0.csv" , "r");
  
}
```

Comment: Please inline the code that's causing this, rather than linking to it.

Comment: okay sorry i edited the question

Comment: Thank you. I would now suggest you edit your code to be readable (proper indentation and whitespace use). Doing so will make debugging much easier.

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger segfault is due to some memory overrun, so you are probably extending beyond a buffer size or similar.

Comment: How is `remove` defined?  _Hint: segmentation faults typically occur either because of an issue with allocating and freeing memory, or an out of bounds array access._

Comment: i should also mention that i get the error when scanf is 1 so when the create_array function is called . When scanf is 4 so when delete_arrays is called i dont get the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These three lines will cause a problem:

```
char str[(int)((ceil(log10(matrix[i][j]))+1)*sizeof(char))];
sprintf(str , "%d " , matrix[i][j]);
fprintf(fout ,"%s" , str);
```

The expression `(int)((ceil(log10(matrix[i][j])) + 1` will produce `1` from a matrix value of `1`, but `char str[1];` won't be enough for the nul-terminated string.

And when the matrix value is `<= 0` the logarithm is undefined. In my test with `0` it attempted to define `char str[-2147483648];`

You don't use `str` for anything else, so I suggest you remove those three lines and use this one simple line instead:

```
fprintf(fout,"%d ", matrix[i][j]);
```

---

**Update**

Another fault is in the file opening: wrong mode

```
FILE *last = fopen("lastnum.csv" , "w");
```

should be

```
FILE *last = fopen("lastnum.csv" , "r");
```

and always *check that `fopen()` succeeds!*

```
if(fout == NULL) {
    /* handle error */
}
if(last == NULL) {
    /* handle error */
}
```

and always check that `fgets()` succeeds too.

```
if(fgets(c , sizeof c , last)) == NULL) {  // changed the 'magic' 20
    /* handle error */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help although very helpful your answer did sadly not fix my issue

Comment: It began as comment but outgrew it. Can you please narrow down the problem a bit? There are 6 menu options. *Where* exactly does it segfault?

Comment: Good point. It happens when the first option is chosen so basically when the create_array() function is called